# how to give read access to logs

Tags: logging

How can i give read access to logs for other users?
Perhaps the solution is to set group for this files and add some users there.
But how to do that for /var/log/maillog?
I mean, logrotate will reset perms?
If i change group from root to another won't it generate any problems?

Actual state:
-rw-------  1 root   root   337M kwi 22 15:40 maillog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an entry to `/etc/logrotate.conf` or wherever your config for the particular log is (most likely in `/etc/logrotate.d/<blah>`)

`create 0664 root utmp`

This tells logrotate to create a new log with 664 permissions and make it owned by user `root` and group `utmp`.

You will probably want something like `create 0644 root root`, unless you only want a specific group to have read access. in that case make it `create 0640 root <your group>`

Answer (score 1):

What syslog engine are you using? `syslog-ng` may be handling file permissions.

You will have lines such as:

```
# Default permissions
options { perm(0640); }; 

# Custom file target
destination localmessages { file("/var/log/localmessages" perm(0644)); };
```

If you're using `syslog-ng`, use its capabilities to set your logfile permissions in general.

If you need specific things (i.e. fred needs to see `/var/log/mail`) I recommend using `sudo` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers, i have used sudo and it works brilliant.
Something like that:

user1, user2, user3 ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/cat /var/log/maillog

rgrds